# When using Vue.js in existing HTML CSS website, the arrangement of the div is not as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a website created using HTML, CSS and Javascript. Now, I wanted to integrate Vue.js into it. I have a page shop.html. When trying to list the products using data from Vue, the data gets populated correctly, but I lost the bootstrap styling of it. Is there a way to retain the bootstrap styling?

My HTML div part of the app is as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center">
<div class="tab-content ftco-animate" id="v-pills-tabContent">
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-0" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-0-tab">
<div id="app" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" v-for="product in products" :id="product.id">
        <div class="menu-entry">
            <a href="#" class="img" style="background-image: url(images/menu-1.jpg);"></a>
            <div class="text text-center pt-4">
               <h3><a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a></h3>
               <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
               <p class="price"><span style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-size: 20px">₹</span><span>{{ product.price }}
                                                        / kg</span></p>
               <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary">Add to Cart</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my ecommerce-main.js (Vue)

```
var app = new Vue({

el: '#app',
data: {
    products: [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Bajji',
            description: 'Fried in flour',
            price: '20'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Sandwich',
            description: 'Veggies in Bread',
            price: '30'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            name: 'Juice',
            description: 'Blended fruits',
            price: '40'
        },
    ] 


},
mounted() {
    console.log('We are mounted');
}
})
```

The screenshot of what it should look like (how I designed using CSS) is as follows:
[image: Bootstrap set to col-md-4]

But, what I get is as follows:
[image]

I suppose I had trouble with bootstrap, but my other simple bootstrap project works perfectly fine. Couldn't find what went wrong.

PS: I'm using Parallax scrolling effect too, on my page.

Comment: seems to be a width issue, can you create snippet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bootstrap but `class="col-md-3" lg="3"` looks slightly suspicious to me, shouldn't that be something like `class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"`?

Comment: agree with @LarsBeck 
one more thing could be happend that ur div is inside another div which with is around 30% of main div. find that one and remove that width

Comment: I'm sorry. I was trying out bootstrap-vue and so used lg="3", which did not work. I now removed it.

Comment: @sayalok I tried that too. Doesn't help.

Comment: @Justcode What codes should I add in the snippet? Or can I share my github link?

Comment: go to developer tools and check what is limiting it, there is some css that you dont want,

Comment: @BalajiKartheeswaran debug it in console which part of ur html takes less width then u expect. or upload it in somewhere where anoy other can debug it. its css issue its hard to find out the problem by observing 500 line codes

Comment: @sayalok Thanks for your effort. Could you please suggest where I could share so others can degug it?

Comment: I've added two more previous div to the code snippet here. I suppose there might be a problem in col-md-12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added col-md-12 class to the second div too and it worked. Doesn't the parent div's col-md-12 apply for the child? I don't know why I should repeat it again.

```
<div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center">
<div class="col-md-12 tab-content ftco-animate" id="v-pills-tabContent">
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-0" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-0-tab">
<div id="app" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" v-for="product in products" :id="product.id">
        <div class="menu-entry">
            <a href="#" class="img" style="background-image: url(images/menu-1.jpg);"></a>
            <div class="text text-center pt-4">
               <h3><a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a></h3>
               <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
               <p class="price"><span style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-size: 20px">₹</span><span>{{ product.price }}
                                                        / kg</span></p>
               <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary">Add to Cart</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```